# Python Zip & list problem (TypeError: 'list' object is not callable)

Tags: python-3.x, list, zip

I have used many similar sample codes from the web, but none of them work and produce errors.Please tell me how to solve this problem,thanks

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = ["a","b","c"]
new_list = list(zip(list1,list2))
new_list
```

Comment: What's error you got?  and which Python version you've been running?  -In Python3+ this should work fine.  Please confirm.

Comment: you've probably assigned something to `zip` or `list` name before.

Comment: I want the output is [(1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c")] ，if i use new_list = tuple(zip(list1,list2)) the output is ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'))

Comment: the error is " 'list' object is not callable  " and my python is 3.10

Comment: when I restart my jupyter，this code can run！！！ thanks！！